# How can I expose the K8S Namespace Name to an environment variable in Kubernetes deployment file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can I expose the K8S Namespace Name to an environment variable in Kubernetes deployment file?

This section is from my deployment yaml:

```
        - name: JAVA_OPTIONS # Jetty JAVA_OPTIONS
          value: >-
            -server
            -Xms$(MIN_MEMORY) -Xmx$(MAX_MEMORY) -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 
-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true    
-Dpod.name=$(POD_NAME) -Dsome.key.tags=$(POD_NAME),[K8S_NAMESPACE_NAME]
```

is there a system variable I can use to add it to

```
some.key.tags=$(POD_NAME),[K8S_NAMESPACE_NAME]
```

If not, I think I have in on my Kustomization.yaml file

```
namespace: default
```

maybe I can read it in the deployment yaml from the Kustomization.yaml ?

Comment: You tagged this question with [tag:kubernetes-helm] but your fragment doesn't seem to include any Helm `{{ ... }}` template blocks, and you mention Kustomize in the text; are you actually using Helm?  (There is an easy Helm answer and a harder plain-Kubernetes answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an environment variable for your container:
and then you can read it using

some.key.tags=$(POD_NAME),$(NAMESPACE)

```
- name: NAMESPACE
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```